# How to iterate correctly over the composed result of a Cypher query in Java Neo4J

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

I would like to execute and print a result of a Cypher (Neo4J) query called from Java, but the result is composed from more than one node type — for example `RETURN u, g`. How do I display **all types** in the result?

I tried calling `row.get("u");` or `row.get("g");` but both result in `NullPointerException` for the following `g`s or `u`s respectively.

```
String q = "MATCH (u:user) OPTIONAL MATCH (u)-[:OWNS]-(g:group) RETURN u, g";
Result res = DB.execute(q);
while (res.hasNext()) {
    Map<String, Object> row = res.next();
    Node n = (Node) row.get("u");
    System.out.println(n.getAllProperties());
}
```

How should I use the `row.get("");` to go through different types of result nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I realized the result is returning **pairs of user and their group**, which MAY NOT exist. i.e:

```
+------+-------+
| user | group |
+------+-------+
|  u1  |   g1  |
|  u1  |   g2  |
|  u2  |  null |
|  u3  |   g3  |
+------+-------+
```

The solution for pairs of nodes from the result is then:

```
while (res.hasNext()) {
    Map<String, Object> row = res.next();
    Node n = (Node) row.get("u");
    if (row.get("g") != null) { //that was causing the NullPointerException
        Node g = (Node) row.get("g");
        System.out.println(n.getAllProperties() + ": " + g.getAllProperties());
    } else System.out.println(n.getAllProperties());
}
```